# SwiftUI: DropDelegate for List cell

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-ondrop

I'm trying to implement a DropDelegate in SwiftUI. A problem I've encountered is that the `.onDrop()` view modifier is not supported for List (at least not the individual cells). The functions defined in the DropDelegate are not called. One simple solution is to embed the data, not in a List, but in a ScrollView. I would like to avoid this solution as you lose a lot of other niceties that come with List. Any idea how I can go about fixing this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var emojis = ["Happy ", "Apple ", "Bus ", "Stopwatch ⏱️", "Sus ", "Toilet "]
    @State private var draggedEmoji: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        List { // Simple solution is to chang List to ScrollView...
            ForEach(emojis, id: \.self) { emoji in
                Text(emoji)
                    .listRowBackground(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
                                .padding(.vertical, 3)
                    )
                    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                .onDrag {
                    print("Dragging '\(emoji)'") // Now we are dragging this...
                    self.draggedEmoji = emoji
                    return NSItemProvider()
                }
                .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: EmojiDropDelegate(destination: emoji))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EmojiDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
    let destination: String
    
    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        print("Entered '\(destination)'")
    }
    
    func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
        print("Exited '\(destination)'")
    }
    
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Re-order inside your list? Drag and drop inside your app? Drag and drop outside your app? That would be really different things.

Comment: You will also need to work with objects conforming `identifiable `instead of plain strings, otherwise the list could fail as soon as you add more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.onDrag` and `.onDrop` to re-order a `List`.

Do it with `.onMove`:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var emojis = ["Happy ", "Apple ", "Bus ", "Stopwatch ⏱️", "Sus ", "Toilet "]
    @State private var draggedEmoji: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(emojis, id: \.self) { emoji in
                Text(emoji)
                    .listRowBackground(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                .fill(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
                                .padding(.vertical, 3)
                    )
                    .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .onMove { from, to in
                emojis.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
            }
        }
    }
}
```